# PHP ECHO giving strange results

Tags: php, echo

I ran into this when I was just trying to echo out some data.  Any idea why PHP acts like this?

Code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
   echo "NO parenthesis : " . $i+1 . "\n";
   echo "WITH parenthesis : " . ($i+1) . "\n";
}
```

output:

```
1
WITH parenthesis : 1
1
WITH parenthesis : 2
1
WITH parenthesis : 3
1
WITH parenthesis : 4
1
WITH parenthesis : 5
1
WITH parenthesis : 6
1
WITH parenthesis : 7
1
WITH parenthesis : 8
1
WITH parenthesis : 9
1
WITH parenthesis : 10
```

Comment: AH!  Thanks!  I searched for an answer before I posted but did not find one.  Thanks for the link! :-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php